# Powershell - Output to a textbox

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm creating a basic GUI for internal staff to share calenders on behalf of other users.

I currently have a button click to get the permissions of the calendar. How would I update the textbox called 'calendarGetOutput?'

```
    $User = $inputCalendarGet.Text
    $CalendarGet = Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity ${user}:\Calendar 
    $calendarGetOutput.text = ???
```

[image: Output not multi-line]

Comment: Depends on what properties you want shown.. Something like `$calendarGetOutput.Text = ($CalendarGet | Select-Object User, AccessRights | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String)` perhaps?

Comment: @Theo Would it work in a similar way for a ListBox? Ideally, it would show more than one line of text. Unless TextBox's can be multi-line?

Comment: Just set the [Multiline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.multiline) property to `$true`

Answer (score 1):

1. make your textbox much larger vertically, so it can contain more than one line of text
2. set these properties to it:

   ```
   $calendarGetOutput.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font 'Consolas', 10  # or any other monospaced font
   $calendarGetOutput.Multiline  = $true
   $calendarGetOutput.WordWrap   = $false
   $calendarGetOutput.ScrollBars = 'Both'
   $calendarGetOutput.Anchor     = 'Left, Top, Right, Bottom'  # so it can grow/shrink with the form
   ```
3. get the mailboxpermissions and have `Format-Table` create a nice table view from the properties you are interested in and add a button click handler that does this:

   ```
   $theButton.Add_Click({ 
       $User = $inputCalendarGet.Text
       $Perms = Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity ${user}:\Calendar
       $calendarGetOutput.Text = $Perms | Select-Object User, AccessRights | 
                                 Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String
   })
   ```

Comment: With the permissions table, it seems to do show permissions of the logged in user, instead of the textbox input?

Comment: @Elliottconnor2 Of course, you may not have access to some parameters if they're not included in the permissions [assigned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/find-exchange-cmdlet-permissions?view=exchange-ps) to you. One can only see what is allowed.